# Change behavior of tab erasing in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I would like to Change behavior of tab erasing in the WinEdt editor. When I insert a tab (pressing the tab key), it does insert a tab, but if right after that I press backspace to erase it, it erases single space characters, one at a time. Thus, in order to erase a full tab I need to press backspace e.g. 4 times. Is it possible to change the program behavior so that backspace deletes the full tab inserted (just as, e.g., Notepad++ does)?
Thanks and regards, Jorge.

Comment: Are you really sure that you insert a TAB after pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and not 4 spaces? Nonetheless to "delete" the TAB/4 spaces you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Stefan! Shift+Tab does seem to erase the tab. As to what am I actually inserting, I don't really know: is there a way to make Winedt display the whitespace characters like space, tab, line return, etc?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Would you write an answer?

Comment: @Arzigoglu, sure. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have written your document in WinEdt it is very likely that there are no (real) TABs in it. By default pressing <kbd>↹ TAB</kbd> 4 spaces are inserted.

Nonetheless instead of using <kbd>⇦ Backspace</kbd> you could press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↹ TAB</kbd> to delete either a TAB or (up to) 4 spaces.

---

To set options regarding the TAB in WinEdt goto
           
    *Options > Options Interface > Font Schemes: ... > Tabs*
where you can e.g. set

- the TAB length
- how TABs "behave"
- if TABs should be drawn
- if TABs are allowed as input chars
- if a TAB should be inserted when <kbd>↹ TAB</kbd> is pressed

After applying your settings don't forget to press the
           
    *Load Current Script*
button!

---

(To test, if you have TABs inside your document you could also do a simple search in the file(s), but therefore you have to ensure that you really have a TAB in the search bar. I ensure this by copying it from another application.)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Using the aforementioned procedure, I set TAB_ALLOW_KEYBOARD=1 and now the editor is actually inserting tabs instead of spaces.